# Can we backup only one availability zone for AZ replicated Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

Since my Cassandra cluster is replicated across three availability zones, I would like to backup only one availability zone to lower the backup costs. I have also experimented restoring nodes in a single availability zone and got back most of my data in a test environment. I would like to know if there are any drawbacks to this approach before deploying this solution in production. Is anyone following this approach in your production clusters?

Note: As I backup at regular intervals, I know that I may loose updates happened to other two AZ nodes quorum at the time of snapshot but that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup only specific dc, or even nodes.
AFAIK, the only drawback is does your data consistent/up-to-date, and since you can afford to lose some data it shouldn't be a problem. And if you, for example performing writes with ALL consistency level, the data should be up-to-date on all nodes.

BUT, you must be sure that your data is indeed replicated between multi a-z, by playing with rack/dc properties or using ec2 switch that supports multi a-z.

EDIT:

> Global Snapshot
>
> Running nodetool snapshot is only run on a single node at a time. 
>   This only creates a partial backup of your entire data.  You will want
>   to run nodetool snapshot on all of the nodes in your cluster.  But
>   it’s best to run them at the exact same time, so that you don’t have
>   fragmented data from a time perspective.  You can do this a couple of
>   different ways.  The first, is to use a parallel ssh program to
>   execute the nodetool snapshot command at the same time.  The second,
>   is to create a cron job on each of the nodes to run at the same time. 
>   The second assumes that your nodes have clocks that are in sync, which
>   Cassandra relies on as well.

Link to the page:
http://datascale.io/backing-up-cassandra-data/

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to official documentation/blog that states this?

Comment: Added link to "docs". Since cassandra snapshot is just a hardlink performed on the node level, it is up to you what you want to backup.